# Refactoring jquery code to angular js codes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to refactor the jquery related code to angular code.

I have the following use case. There are four `a` tags, on click of each `a` tag, its following event handler called which makes certain `div` visible. For example one of the `a` tag event handler looks like this:

```
    $("#fistdiv").css('display','none');
    $("#seconddiv").css('display','none');
    $("#thriddiv").css('display','none');
    $("#fourthdiv").css('display','block');
```

In this case `fourthdiv` is made visible. And each `div` shows particular contents in a table.

I want to refactor this jquery-code to angular-js. How that can be done? Rather than falling into querying dom and binding event handlers, how can be made in angular terms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty naive approach but it should be something you actually need:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="visible = 1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="visible = 2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="visible = 3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="visible = 4">Link 4</a>

<div ng-show="visible == 1">Some content 1</div>
<div ng-show="visible == 2">Some content 2</div>
<div ng-show="visible == 3">Some content 3</div>
<div ng-show="visible == 4">Some content 4</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QyCzUuBwB4yoAbmsgXid?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow